# display:none with angular datatables

Tags: css, angular-datatables

I have a table which should be hidden when the page loads and is shown only on selection of a checkbox.

```
<table width="100%" id="C" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptionsfeature" class="celltable" style="display: none;">
```

I also tried it in css file

```
#C {

    display: none;
}
```

It works if i remove the data tables . So can i not use css styling with data tables ? because other properties are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hide table parent container

```
<div id="hide-table"><table width="100%" id="C" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptionsfeature" class="celltable" style="display: none;"></div>

#hide-table{display:none;}
```

Comment: if it is not working try #hide-table{display:none !important;}

Comment: Angular datatables, as in angularjs? Why not using ng-if?